# Replace a backslash comma to double backslash comma

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How do I change replace a `"\,"` to `"\\,"` ? So that, the string `OU=b\,aditi,DC=zeus2,DC=com` becomes `OU=b\\,aditi,DC=zeus2,DC=com` ??

I need some javascript solution, regex or replace function will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
str = str.replace(/\\,/g, "\\\\,");
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/6)

```js
var str = 'OU=b\\,aditi,DC=zeus2,DC=com';
alert("before: "+str);
str = str.replace(/\\,/g, '\\\\,');
alert("after: "+str);
```

Comment: That would replace it with… the same thing. ``\\\\``!

Comment: Strings still use ``\`` for escapes. Try it out with `alert("\\,")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=\\,)
```

Try this.Replace by `\`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/25

```
var re = /(?=\\,)/gm; 
var str = 'OU=b\,aditi,DC=zeus2,DC=com';
var subst = '\\'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var re = /\\/; 
var str = 'OU=b\\,aditi,DC=zeus2,DC=com';
var subst = '\\\\'; 
 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD8kP6/1)